# Bind links of router link angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router, routerlink

I'm working on an Angular4 project. Everything works great till now, but I'm finding myself hard coding the path of routerlink directly into the html templates:

```
<a routerLink="/example" >link</a>
```

I want to avoid it somehow and bind it to the routing module I have.

Is it possible (and logical)?
What is the best practice regarding paths?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For binding you need `[]` or `{{}}` (never both together) like

```
[routerLink]="fieldWithPath"
```

or

```
routerLink="{{fieldWithPath}}"
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  fieldWithPath:string = '/example';
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get the link directly from the router and not write '/example' on every component that should link to /example

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "directly from the router". You can create a my-example-link component if you need it often or add a getter to you component that returns the value from a constant or similar.

Comment: I have a Routing module that define all the routes in the app. it has a line {path: 'example', component: exampleComponent} I want to import the path from there instead of decoupling it in my code

Comment: Create constants and use them in routes and in components.